# Create/Update related model via parent model in Loopback

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

Let's say I have a Configuration model. Configuration has one-to-many relationship with ConfigurationParameter model like this:

*configuration.json (relevant part)*

```
{
  "name": "Configuration",
  "properties": {
    "title": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "relations": {
    "configuration-parameters": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "ConfigurationParameter",
      "foreignKey": "configurationId"
    }
  }
}
```

*configuration-parameter.js (relevant part)*

```
{
  "name": "ConfigurationParameter",
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "value": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  }
  "relations": {
    "configuration": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Configuration",
      "foreignKey": "configurationId"
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a way (a setting?) to create a configuration together with configuration parameters in a single call?

I would expect something like this:

```
POST /configurations
```

with

```
{
  "title": "o1",
  "configuration-parameters": [
    {
      "name": "n1",
      "value": "v1"
    }
  ]
}
```

I could create a [default scope](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Model+definition+JSON+file#ModeldefinitionJSONfile-Defaultscope) like this:

```
"scope": {
  "include": {
    "relation": "configuration-parameters"
  }
}
```

That's fine for GET operations, configuration parameters are included in results of a query, but it doesn't work for POST/PUT operations.

I could use [embedded relations](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Embedded+models+and+relations), but then according to documentation, if I use relational database, I end up with stringified-JSON format for a related model data. That's not something I would like.

The only other way, which comes to mind are hooks (remote or operation). Is there something else, what I'm missing ?

[Related github issue](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/1481#) (sadly with no satisfying answer)

[Related google groups question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/loopbackjs/bzrSFB2sjsc) (sadly with no answer)

Comment: I think is not possible, i create observe hook for save relations after the creation.

Comment: yes, it's not possible. what you need to do is to call 
`Configuration.afterRemote('create', callback)` where callback is your function that will create those **ConfigurationParameter** entities